# how to do Firebase Pagination in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, firebase

I would like to know how to sort 50 messages in a page1, and load the next 50 messages when it hit the bottom of the tabview in firebase. Thanks

Comment: anything you tried ?

Comment: Sort by what? Can you add your firebase structure to your question as text? (Firebase Dashboard, Export button).

Answer (score 1):

This will give you 25 recent entry

```
      Firebase *fref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"your firebase url"]
     [[fref queryLimitedToLast:25] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    }];
```

and when table hits the bottom call this

```
- (FQuery *) queryStartingAtValue:(id)startValue;
```